# Send message to self-Chat in Microsoft Teams using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send a message to my **self-Chat in Microsoft Teams** through a Graph API call but can't find the ID of this specific chat. For the record, this type of chat [was introduced to Teams in June, 2022](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-launches-chat-with-self-feature/m-p/3498752).

By reading the [Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list), it's possible to list all chats available for a specific user using the following API call (in this case, myself):

[GET] https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/

Yet, I can't seem to find my self-chat in there. The chat itself is already created since I wrote messages in it but it doesn't appear in the call response.

I've tried to filter the results by most recent results, by filtering on my own name or by filtering by `ChatType`, but it was still missing.

Is anyone aware of a way to get the ID of a user self-chat in Microsoft Teams?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self chat is a special kind, You can use this endpoint to communicate with it:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats/48:notes/messages

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, it works wonders!

Is that documented somewhere? I think I missed it in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's documented yet. Figured it out by looking at the link in Teams web client.

Comment: thanks!!!
just adding my call for extra info 

curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats/48:notes/messages' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer Token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}'

Comment: Has anyone been able to get a notification to pop up when you post a new message?  I've tried setting it to the highest priority with no luck.  I'm trying to use this as a sort of an internal notification system.

Comment: @harrywynn You can try using [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com) 
(formerly Microsoft Flow) instead (the "Post message in chat or channel" action, send as flow bot in the chat with user)

Comment: @David that's actually what I ended up doing in order to get the notifications.  I set up a flow to read a RSS feed and shoot off a message when it pulls new items.

Answer (score 1):

Answering harrywyn's question regarding the pop up notification, you can set it as unread the same as any chat like this:

```py
EndPoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/48:notes/markChatUnreadForUser'
update_chat = {
    "user": {
        "id" : uid,
        "tenantId": TENANT_ID
    }
}
resp = requests.post(EndPoint, headers=headers, verify=False, json=update_chat)
```

Comment: Need code formatting